# Simple Voting System in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple voting-function to our site. Something in it does not work.

```
if(isset($_POST['vote']))
{
    if($_POST['rate'] == "rate_1")
    {
        $rate = 'rate_1';
        $rate_opload = ++$rest['rate_1'];
    }

    if else($_POST['rate'] == "rate_2")
    {
        $rate = 'rate_2';
        $rate_opload = ++$rest['rate_2'];
    }

    if else($_POST['rate'] == "rate_3")
    {
        $rate = 'rate_3';
        $rate_opload = ++$rest['rate_3'];
    }

    if else($_POST['rate'] == "rate_4")
    {
        $rate = 'rate_4';
        $rate_opload = ++$rest['rate_4'];
    }

    if else($_POST['rate'] == "rate_5")
    {
        $rate = 'rate_5';
        $rate_opload = ++$rest['rate_5'];
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO kaffe ('{$rate}') VALUES ('{$rate_opload}')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

There are five different columns as you can see because we needed an average in an other part.
I don't know if it's necessary but here is the option-form

```
<form method=\"post\" id=\"vote\">
  <select name=\"rate\">
    <option value=\"rate_1\" >&#x2605;</option>
    <option value=\"rate_2\" >&#x2605;&#x2605</option>
    <option value=\"rate_3\" >&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</option>
    <option value=\"rate_4\">&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</option>
    <option value=\"rate_5\">&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</option>  
  </select>
  <button type=\"submit\" form=\"vote\" value=\"vote\" class=\"fsSubmitButton\">Rösta</button>
```

Comment: `else if`, not `if else`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Or, because PHP is silly like that, `elseif` without the space in between.

Comment: Yep `elseif` to be exact

Comment: @Duroth: either is fine; `elseif` is just a single keyword to use instead of two separate ones.

Comment: Since no-one else has mentioned it, this database library is now deprecated, and you should really be either escaping or parameter-binding your user inputs. There is no SQL injection vulnerability here, but that may more accident than design!

Comment: What is "if else($_POST['rate'] == "rate_2")"

Answer (score 1):

First you forgot to put name="vote" into your html form

```
<form method=\"post\" id=\"vote\">
<select name=\"rate\">
<option value=\"rate_1\" >&#x2605;</option>
<option value=\"rate_2\" >&#x2605;&#x2605</option>
<option value=\"rate_3\" >&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</option>
<option value=\"rate_4\">&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</option>
<option value=\"rate_5\">&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</option>  
</select>
<button type=\"submit\" name="vote" form=\"vote\" value=\"vote\" class=\"fsSubmitButton\">Rösta</button>
```

Second it's `else if` and not `if else`, your code can be much more compact, nowaday mysql function are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) use mysqli

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");// Connect to database using mysqli function since mysql function are deprecated
if(isset($_POST['vote']))
{
    if($_POST['rate'] == 'rate_1' | $_POST['rate'] == 'rate_2' | $_POST['rate'] == 'rate_3' | $_POST['rate'] == 'rate_4' |$_POST['rate'] == 'rate_5'){
        $rate = $_POST['rate'];
        $rate_opload = ++$rest[$rate];

        $sql = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO kaffe ('{$rate}') VALUES (?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql , $rate_opload);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
     }
}
```

Comment: This narrowly avoids SQL injection by virtue of its safe-listing of possible user inputs. Nevertheless, I would be tempted to pass `$rate` through an escaping function for safety, and that is also not ideal - answers like this perhaps could either switch to parameter binding, or at least mention that this is a better approach. The library in use here is now deprecated.

Comment: Also, it is possible to get the query to fail by getting the inner `if` to not run. I'd move the execution of the query into that clause, since without the two values `$rate` and `$rate_opload`, the query won't run anyway.

Comment: @halfer you're right thanks for the advice I just edited my post:)

Comment: Nearly right! You can't use parameter binding for the column name, that has to come from a safe list or an escaped user input (or that's the case for PDO anyway, and I think it is the case for MySQL regardless of interface library). I should have mentioned that with my original feedback! But good work `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer using ORM make you forget a lot of things ;). Anyway thank you very much for the feedback

Comment: Heh yes, I use Propel often, and I can afford to forget SQL mostly `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
 if(isset($_POST['vote']))
```

is not reached, you have to add name="vote" to your submit button